# MVVM pattern books?

Tags: mvvm

are there any MVVM pattern books out there or at least books that handle that topic? I couldn't really find any book about that, any recommendation? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any good books on M-V-VM in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483367/are-there-any-good-books-on-m-v-vm-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3):

- Pro WPF and Silverlight MVVM Effective Application Development with Model-View-ViewModel
  http://apress.com/book/view/1430231629
- Building Enterprise Applications with Windows Presentation Foundation and the Model View ViewModel Pattern
  [http://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Applications-Presentation-Foundation-ViewModel/dp/0735650926/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735650926)
- Silverlight 4 in Action (has a chapter on MVVM)
  [http://www.amazon.com/Silverlight-4-Action-Pete-Brown/dp/1935182374/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182374)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Advanced MVVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038KX9FW) by Josh Smith.  If you already know WPF or Silverlight it's a great intro to MVVM.  Keep in mind that it's an e-book.